# what is the reason for this logstash error : exception=>#< "LogStash" ::Json::ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, grok

I have the following log line

```
{"code":200,"message":"ok","responseBody":{"token":"asdadqwrqwkjrqwejr"},"time":"4545425244"}
```

and using logstash json plugin to parse this log but logstash show following error in logstash-plain.log :

```
exception=>#< "LogStash" ::Json::ParserError: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
```

what is the problem ?
thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception

```
Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
```

is thrown when the the parser reaches the end of the text to be parsed whilst trying to read a value. For example, the following will produce that error because it is missing a closing double quote.

```
input { generator { count => 1 lines => [ '{"message":"ok}' ] } }
filter {  json { source => "message" remove_field => [ "message" ] } }
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => false } } }
```

If it runs out of text whilst reading the name of a field the exception will be `Unexpected end-of-input in field name` (that would happen for `{"message}`).